# how do i set up ssl cert for my website running on ubuntu server in amazon aws?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I have never set up ssl cert before.

I have 2 different domains hosted on the same instance in amazon ec2.

I need to set up ssl certs for both domains. I suspect the steps are the same for both.

http://www.curtis-lamasters.com/2008/07/30/apache2-on-ubuntu-openssl-csr-self-signed-cert/

I have finished sudo a2enmod ssl

I am stuck at the step at navigating to /etc/ssl/private because amazon only gave me a user called ubuntu and not root access.

Please write out for me detailed steps.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the tutorial writer left out `sudo -i` after the `sudo a2enmod ssl` step.  That will get you an interactive root shell, then you can finish the commands as written.

Comment: i wish i can upvote, but i need at least 15 points.

Comment: @keisimone: If you were able to get SSL working, click the checkmark next to my answer to accept it as the correct answer.  I think that will give you points as well.